# Estimate true mean of the maximum of N sample means

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, sampling, extreme-value

Let's say we have N distributions $\mathcal N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$, each with unknown mean $\mu_i$ and unknown standard deviation $\sigma_i$, $i=0,...,N-1$.

For each $i$, $M$ independent random samples are drawn from from the distributions above $x_{ij} \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$, $i=0....N-1, j=0,...,M-1$ with the draws being jointly independent of each other.

Compute $N$ sample means $m_i = \frac1M\sum_j {x_{ij}}$ 
and $N$ sample variances $v_i = \frac{1}{M-1}\sum_j{(x_{ij} - m_i)^2}$.

Search for index $i_{max}$ such that $m_{i_{max}} = \max_i\, m_i$. That is, $i_{max}$ is the index of the random variable with the maximum sample mean.

What is the best unbiased estimate of true mean $\mu_{i_{max}}$? Is it simply $m_{i_{max}}$?

Comment: Your proposed estimator certainly won't be unbiased in general, as demonstrated with the following counterexample. Consider $N = 2$ and suppose WLOG that $\mu_1 > \mu_2$. Then $E[m_{i_{max}}] = E[E[\max(m_1, m_2) | m_2]] >E[\max(E[m_1 | m_2], m_2)] = E[\max(\mu_1,m_2)] >\max(\mu_1, E[m_2]) = \mu_1$ where I used convexity of $\max$ and Jensen's inequality.

Comment: By continuous mapping theorem, however, it is easy enough to show that if your asymptotics fix $N$ and let $M \to \infty$, your proposed estimator will be consistent (you don't even need normality for this).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response and edits, stats_model.  This was my first question on stack exchange... This seems like a great community!